Blender4.0.2 "libpng error: IDAT: CRC error" when using bpy.data.images.load()
def blend(mat_name, file_name):
    blend_scene = bpy.data.scenes[define.SCENE_NAME_BLEND]

    get_bpy_obj('Plane').material_slots[0].material = get_bpy_mat(mat_name)
    blend_scene.render.filepath = os.path.join(define.TEMPORARY_BLENDED_TEXTURE_FOLDER_PATH, file_name)
    bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True, use_viewport=True, scene=define.SCENE_NAME_BLEND)

def load_blended_image(image_name):
    path = os.path.join(define.TEMPORARY_BLENDED_TEXTURE_FOLDER_PATH, image_name)
    target_image = bpy.data.images.get(image_name)
    if not target_image:
        target_image = bpy.data.images.load(path, check_existing=False)
    else:
        target_image.reload()
    return target_image

blend('test_material', 'xxx.png')

#do something

load_blended_image('xxx.png')

I'm running a program in Linux with EEVEE and using background mode. When executing the core code above, an error raised like this:
Fra:0 Mem:3118.68M (Peak 3118.68M) | Time:00:00.01 | Syncing Mesh.001
Fra:0 Mem:3118.68M (Peak 3118.68M) | Time:00:00.01 | Syncing Mesh_LOD0.
libpng error: IDAT: CRC error
ImageInput::read_image() failed: PNG read error: IDAT: CRC error
PNG library error
IMB_ibImageFromMemory: unknown file-format (/root/asset_png/blended_textures/xxxx.png)
GPUTexture: Blender Texture Not Loaded!
Fra:0 Mem:3138.15M (Peak 3150.73M) | Time:00:00.30 | Rendering 1 / 16 samples
Fra:0 Mem:3135.18M (Peak 3150.73M) | Time:00:00.74 | Rendering 16 / 16 samples
Fra:0 Mem:3134.36M (Peak 3167.18M) | Time:00:00.79 | Compositing
Fra:0 Mem:3134.36M (Peak 3167.18M) | Time:00:00.79 | Compositing | Determining resolution
Fra:0 Mem:3134.36M (Peak 3167.18M) | Time:00:00.79 | Compositing | Initializing execution
Fra:0 Mem:3166.43M (Peak 3167.18M) | Time:00:00.83 | Compositing | Tile 1-32
Fra:0 Mem:3166.43M (Peak 3167.18M) | Time:00:00.83 | Compositing | Tile 2-32
Fra:0 Mem:3166.43M (Peak 3167.18M) | Time:00:00.83 | Compositing | Tile 3-32
Fra:0 Mem:3166.43M (Peak 3167.18M) | Time:00:00.83 | Compositing | Tile 4-32
Fra:0 Mem:3166.43M (Peak 3167.18M) | Time:00:00.83 | Compositing | Tile 5-32
Fra:0 Mem:3166.43M (Peak 3167.18M) | Time:00:00.84 | Compositing | Tile 6-32
Fra:0 Mem:3166.43M (Peak 3167.18M) | Time:00:00.84 | Compositing | Tile 7-32

It doesn't happen every time and seems to be caused by accessing an image immediately after it has been rendered.
Any suggestion would be helpful to me, thanks a lot!
update: Two more similiar errors appeared
Fra:0 Mem:5318.78M (Peak 5318.78M) | Time:00:00.02 | Syncing Mesh0.
Fra:0 Mem:5318.79M (Peak 5318.79M) | Time:00:00.02 | Syncing Mesh1.
libpng error: bad adaptive filter value
ImageInput::read_image() failed: PNG read error: bad adaptive filter value
PNG library error
IMB_ibImageFromMemory: unknown file-format (/root/asset_png/blended_textures/xxxxx.png)
GPUTexture: Blender Texture Not Loaded!
Fra:0 Mem:5338.58M (Peak 5350.84M) | Time:00:00.36 | Rendering 1 / 16 samples
Fra:0 Mem:5335.32M (Peak 5350.84M) | Time:00:00.93 | Rendering 16 / 16 samples
Fra:0 Mem:5334.50M (Peak 5367.32M) | Time:00:00.99 | Compositing
Fra:0 Mem:5334.50M (Peak 5367.32M) | Time:00:00.99 | Compositing | Determining resolution
Fra:0 Mem:5334.50M (Peak 5367.32M) | Time:00:00.99 | Compositing | Initializing execution
Fra:0 Mem:5366.57M (Peak 5367.32M) | Time:00:01.03 | Compositing | Tile 1-32

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/blender_render/scripts/utils.py", line 384, in start_render_pipeline
    file_paths = execute_func(rp, define.TEMPORARY_RESULTS_FOLDER_PATH, w=render_size_w)
  File "/root/blender_render/scripts/character_render_pipeline.py", line 86, in execute
    pose1_image_square = pose1_image_raw.crop((0, 0, width, height))
  File "/root/blender_render/blender_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1301, in crop


    self.load()
  File "/root/blender_render/blender_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 312, in load
    raise _get_oserror(err_code, encoder=False)
OSError: unrecognized data stream contents when reading image file
Fra:200 Mem:3021.68M (Peak 3021.68M) | Time:00:00.00 | Syncing Plane

Those errors occurred when loading an image from the local directory, which was saved by Blender using bpy.ops.render.render().

Are you perhaps trying to read the image before rendering is concluded, or before it has fully finished writing it to disk?

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos I tried this demo:
@persistentdef handler(dummy):      print("a")  bpy.app.handlers.render_complete.append(handler) bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True) print("b"),
and the result show that the handler execute earlier than the code behind.
